# Adding more effects to a Unity3d mixer

Tags: unity, audio

I recently started exploring the wonderfull world of audio in unity. I noticed that you can add a bunch of effect modules to a mixer. Now I'm wondering if you can add your own custom effects( for example export a plugin from a audio program or something) and add them to the list. I cant seem to find anything related to the question.

Comment: It looks like you need to go lower-level to access these, using the [Native Audio Plugin SDK](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixerNativeAudioPlugin.html) which [can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/nativeaudioplugins). I don't have experience with this personally, but hopefully this may help you or another user find useful directions to investigate.

Comment: @DMGregory oh boy this is a  treasure. Thanks for the info. If I ever get to writing my own audio mixer plugins or creating a wrapper I will post my result here as a answer.